# MySQL Query Error SQLException

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, sqlexception

I encountered this issue when trying to implement query requests into a program. Connecting to the database without this method works fine, however, this throws a `SQLException`.

```
    String query = "SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM usr WHERE username = admin AND password = pass )";
    boolean result;
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        result = rs.next();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot connect to the database!", e);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Closing the connection.");
        if (con != null)
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ignore) {
                System.out.println("Unknown Error Connecting to MySQL Server!");
            }
    }
```

I brought the query into the method to isolate it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into using Prepared Statements: [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html): They pretty much eliminate having to deal with quoting String/varchar fields. In your case `admin` and `pass` are not properly surrounded w/single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Generally searching for strings - you need to single quote the value - so replace with `'admin'` and `'pass'` in the where clause.

Comment: Ah this fixed it, however, now it always returns true, even if the values are incorrect. Any ideas?

Comment: No, that should work.  I tried a very similar query on one of my MySQL databases and it worked.  Now, the result is either 1 (exists) or 0 (non-exists).   You might want to try running your query directly against the database - by using the mysql command line.